# Firebird API создание базы программно

Tags: c++, sql, qt, firebird

Я использую Firebird API для программного создания базы. Для создания базы я использую код из [этого поста.](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/61465-Create-firebird-database-programmatically-with-Qt?p=292941#post292941)
Проблема в том, что файл базы создается с именем и расширением в верхнем регистре (uppercase). С чем это связано? Файл ibase.h я подключаю к своему проекту Qt.

При использовании Firebird ISQL Tool тот же самый эффект, файл создается в верхнем регистре.
`SQL> CREATE DATABASE 'C:/data.fdb' USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8`

Comment: А вы в отладчике пробовали запускать и посмотреть, на каком этапе строка в верхний регистр преобразуется? С большой вероятностью строка преобразуется в верхний регистр в вашем проекте, а не в функции по ссылке.

Comment: Мне так не кажется.

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема? в Windows пути "C:\DATA.FDB" и "c:\data.fdb" равны. Все файловые системы, поддерживаемые Windows, не регистрочувствительны

Comment: Хочу чтобы были в нижнем регистре.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Проблема в том, что файл базы создается с именем и расширением в верхнем регистре (uppercase)

Это **не проблема**. Файловые системы windows не различают регистр имени файла.

> С чем это связано?

С тем, что Firebird - кроссплатформенная система. В UNIX 'data.fdb' и 'DATA.FDB' - это разные файлы. А в Windows - одинаковые. Чтобы все внутренние механизмы не считали их разными, в Windows они приводятся к одному регистру. Выбор в пользу верхнего (а не нижнего) регистра обусловлен, видимо, тем, что так хранились имена файлов в самой древней файловой системе windows - FAT16.

Если вам "религия" не позволяет оставить файл так, то можете после создания отключиться от базы и переименовать файл.